# How I solve this no main manifest attribute, in 2-Variable.jar error in my kotlin program

Tags: kotlin, programmers-notepad

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q8cbW.png)

`fun main(args: Array<String>) { var name="Sujoy" name="Sujoy Maity" print(name) }`
When I save this code as 2-Variable.kt and run this code in visual studio code.
Then VS code thrown an error that:
no main manifest attribute, in 2-Variable.jar
So how to solve this error?